# Tomcat Instance with Multiple WebApps - Sessions Interfering Each Other

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I am trying to run multiple WebApps on a single Tomcat instance. My goal is to have each one accessible at the root context for a given port e.g.

```
http://server:8081
http://server:8082
...
```

I have given each one a separate "Service", "Connector", "Engine", and "Host" entry within server.xml. Everything seems to work fine except that once I've logged into the first app, if I then login to the second the first loses its session information and logs out.

If I edit server.xml and run them on their original contexts e.g.

```
http://server:8081/jenkins
http://server:8082/jenkins
...
```

everything seems to work fine. This leads me to believe that the session is somehow shared when they are both in the root context, even though they have separate connectors, etc. Any idea what I am doing that is causing this to happen?

I confirmed that the two instances share the same jsessionID and that when I login with one instance, the other loses its first jsessionid and takes on the second, effectively losing its authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [sessionCookiePath](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) context parameter. I didn’t tried it myself but I think that this might be the trick you’re looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I've begun experimenting with this myself but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

**Tomcat 7**

Modify file $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml, add an **attribute** *sessionCookieName*

```
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context sessionCookieName="JSESSIONID_SERVER_01">
 <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
 <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
 <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
 <!--
 <Manager pathname="" />
 -->
 <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
 on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
 <!--
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
 -->
</Context>
```